# Regex in C to restrict Extended ASCII character set

Tags: c, regex, posix, extended-ascii

I need a regex expression in C able to match everything but first 32 characters from extended ASCII with length greater than 0. I thought the easiest way to do that would be pattern like `"^[^\\x00-\\x20]+$"`, but it's not working as I expected. For some reason it won't match any character from 48 to 92. Any ideas what's wrong with this pattern and how can I fix it?

[Link to Extended ASCII character set table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#/media/File:Table_ascii_extended.png)

Comment: Try `^[[:print:]]+$`

Comment: Why use Regex? This would probably perform much faster using a naive loop with a `switch` statement (and far faster with intrinsics)...

Comment: It won't match characters from 127 to 255

Comment: Are you using the Posix regex library?

Comment: I'm using regex.h library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Posix regex library (i.e. the functions in `regex.h`, including `regcomp` and `regexec`) does *not* interpret standard C backslash sequences. It really doesn't need to, since C will do those expansions when you compile the character string literal. (This is something you have to think about if you accept regular expressions from user input.) The only use of `\` in a regex is to escape a special character (in `REG_EXTENDED` mode), or to make a character special (in basic regex mode, which should be avoided.)

So if you want to exclude characters from `\x01` to `\x20`, you would write:

```
 "^[^\x01-\x20]+$"
```

Note that you must supply the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to `regcomp` for that to work.

As you might note, that does not exclude NUL (`\x00`). There's no way to insert a NUL into a regex pattern because NUL is not a valid character inside a C character string; it will terminate the string. For the same reason, it's pointless to try to exclude NUL characters from a C string, because there cannot be any. However, if it made you feel better, you could use:

```
"^[\x21-\xFF]+$"
```

Semantically, those two regex patterns are identical (at least, in the default "C" locale and assuming `char` is 8 bits).

The character class as you wrote it, `[^\\x00-\\x20]`, contains everything but the character `x` and the range from `0` (48) to `\` (92). (That range overlaps with the characters `0`, `2` and `\`, which are named explicitly, some of them twice.)

Answer (score -1):

Never used regex in `C`. I would do it next way using `unsigned char` to fit EASCII

```
void match(const unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dst) {
    while (*src) {
        if (*src >= 32) {
            *dst++ = *src++;
        } else {
            src++;
        }
    }
    *dst = 0;
}
```